# Finding the latest modified id

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

| id | new_id | modification date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2022-01-01 |
| 10 | 20 | 2022-02-13 |
| 20 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |

I am trying to add a column with the "latest id":

| id | new_id | modification date | latest id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2022-01-01 | 20 |
| 3 |  |  | 3 |

I have tried using

```
LEAD(new_id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY modification date DESC)
```

But it just gave an id from the next rows, how should I approach this?
I thought about using JOIN, but I do not know the number of times the id was changed, the same goes with FOR loop

Comment: Have you tried fetching in a WHILE loop until new_id is null?

Comment: this looks more like a case for recursive CTE as you need to follow th chain ti newid id NULL or emoty

Comment: @freakish It seems that WHILE can not be written in the SELECT clause, so I did not try it

Comment: @gbox you can alwayse execute an anonymous code block via `DO ... END`.

Answer (score 0):

If modification date always updated when new_id arrive, then for latest modified id I use:

```
select id, new_id, modification date
from(
select id, new_id, modification date, row_number() over(partition by id order by modification_date DESC) as rn
from table) x
where rn = 1
```